Failed to compile, Attempted import error: 'e' is not exported from 'react' (imported as 'e')

My react 18 project smoothly run in my local pc, but when i command for build
the message show's as below
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Attempted import error: 'e' is not exported from 'react' (imported as 'e').


I don't find any 'e' in my whole project
Note:  React-18
Please any suggestion is appreciated

Do you run a minified code in your prod env?
